# C++ Pointers. How to assign value to a pointer struct?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int vin;
    char* make;
    char* model;
    int year;
    double fee;
}car;
```

Then I create a pointer of type car

```
car *tempCar;
```

How do I assign values to the tempCar? I'm having trouble

```
        tempCar.vin = 1234;         
        tempCar.make = "GM";
        tempCar.year = 1999;
        tempCar.fee = 20.5;
```

Compiler keeps saying tempCar is of type car*. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the -> operator on pointers, like this:

```
car * tempCar = new car();
tempCar->vin = 1234;
tempCar->make = "GM";
//...
delete tempCar;
```

Also, don't forget to allocate memory for tempCar if you're using a pointer like this.  That's what 'new' and 'delete' do.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to allocate memory here. The pointer may be pointing at a local struct on the stack. `car ferrari; tempCar = &ferrari;`

Comment: Note that its probably C code due to the explicitly typedef'd struct.

Answer (score 16):

You have to dereference the pointer first (to get the struct).

Either:

```
(*tempCar).make = "GM";
```

Or:

```
tempCar->make = "GM";
```

Answer (score 5):

`tempCar->vin = 1234`

The explanation is quite simple : `car*` is a pointer on `car`. It's mean you have to use the operator `->` to access data. By the way, `car*` must be allocated if you want to use it.

The other solution is to use a declaration such as `car tempCar;`. The `car` struct is now on the stack you can use it as long as you are in this scope. With this kind of declaration you can use `tempCar.vin` to access data.

Comment: Declaring an instance (as with **car tempCar;**) can easily be on the stack and isn't necessarily *static*

Comment: I know my sentence wasn't clear, i meant static allocation in opposition to a dynamic allocation :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your tempCar is a pointer, then you have to allocate memory for it and assign like this:

```
tempCar = new car();
tempCar->vin = 1234;         
tempCar->make = "GM";
tempCar->year = 1999;
tempCar->fee = 20.5;
```

Otherwise declare tempCar in this way: `car tempCar;`

Answer (score -1):

Change your car *temp to below line:

```
 car *tempCar = (car *)malloc(sizeof(car));

 tempCar->vin = 1234;         
 tempCar->make = "GM";
 tempCar->year = 1999;
 tempCar->fee = 20.5;
```

Comment: undefined behaviour according to the c++ standard. `new` should be used for raw dynamic memory allocation in C++, not malloc.

Answer (score -2):

People, be careful when using new, this is not Java, it's C++, don't use parentheses when you don't have parameters:  tempCar = new car;

Comment: Why "be careful"?  It's a style issue and I definitely disagree: use the parens.

Comment: Not a style issue. With parenthesis, the members in a POD type will be default-constructed. Parenthesis are usually preferred, in my experience.